# Jquery Draggable Div change background on drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Making a fun little activity for my daughters 1st grade school website.

I have several pictures in div's the kids can move around on the virtual living room using Jquery Draggable and Droppable, but my problem comes from where I want to have a light bulb png image (#bulb1) when dragged over the lamp (#lamp1) that the background image bulb-off.png of (#bulb1) will change to image bulb-on.png once dropped on (#lamp1).

I am able to get the background image to change now, I have the tooltip that shows with the vocabulary for the kidds to learn, but I do not seem to have the ability to remove the dropped image the same way it was placed, and with the current settings, the tool tip will stop... Seems to be a little messy now.

I have been reading a lot on the Jquery site, but not seeing anything to put me on track to get this to work.

Basically I am back at the beginning (cleaned up my code mess).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
$( '#bulb1' ).draggable({
containment: '.shelf', 
     helper: 'clone'
});
$( '#lamp1, #laml2, #lamp3).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/bulb-on.png)').tooltip();
},
out: function( event, ui ) {
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/bulb-off-off.png)'); 
}
});
});
</script>
```

Any assistance would be great !

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Hi, could you show the stuff you tried and what happened, CSS classes and the images they contain, etcetera? That way we can see it for ourselves. Also, +1 for this great project.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply... I added a few things I was trying under my first question... Everything is moving around well, but this image change would sure give it the feel of animation that the kids love ! I am having fun too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$(this).addClass( 'img src="images/bulb-on.png"' );
```

Try:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://yoursite.idk/images/bulb-on.png)');
```

Comment: That is great... When the div is dropped, both images are in the same place. Now I made a change to (.hide) the bulb-off.png, now I can't get it back... trying to use the (.hover) to bring back the #bulb1 div... always something hahaha...